# Elegant way to access first child using JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm a bit confused with the Newtonsoft.Json `JObject` interface. Say I need to access the `'foo'` property of the first child in my JSON object. My C# code:

```
string json = @"{
    'someUnknownKey': { 'foo': 'bar' }
}";

JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);

JObject child = o.First.ToObject<JProperty>().Value.ToObject<JObject>();
string s = child["foo"].ToObject<string>();
```

This works, but is there a more elegant way to do it, without all the `JProperty`/`JObject` conversions?

EDIT: I would like to stress that the key name `someUnknownKey` is unknown so I can't use it in my code.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you do need *a* conversion to indicate that you expect the first child token to be a property, but you can do it more simply than your current code:

```
string json = @"{
    'someUnknownKey': { 'foo': 'bar' }
}";

JObject root = JObject.Parse(json);
Console.WriteLine(((JProperty) root.First).Value["foo"]);
```

Or to break it down slightly more clearly:

```
JObject root = JObject.Parse(json);
JProperty property = (JProperty) root.First;
Console.WriteLine(property.Value["foo"]);
```

Another option is to use the `Properties()` method to ask for the first property instead of the first child token. That way you don't need any conversion.

```
JObject root = JObject.Parse(json);        
Console.WriteLine(root.Properties().First().Value["foo"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query the json object as dynamic:

```
string json = @"{
    'someUnknownKey': { 'foo': 'bar' }
}";

dynamic o = JArray.Parse(json);

string child = o.someUnknownKey.foo;
```

Look here for a reference https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonDynamic.htm

Alternatively you can use [] to access json properties:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
string value = (string)(o['someUnknownKey']['foo']);
```

Comment: Please see my comment to user1672994.

Comment: It seems the situation here changes rapidly so I do not know which comment you meant specifically :)

Comment: Ah, they've deleted their answer. Basically, the name "someUnknownKey" suggests that the OP doesn't know the name of the key, so any answer which assumes that can be present in the source code won't be helpful to them, I suspect.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
var jtk = o.Descendants().First().Children().First().Value<string>("foo")
```